# Xamarin Forms text layout differences between iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm working my way through Charles Petzold's "*Creating Mobile Apps with Xamarin.Forms Preview Edition 2*" and I was playing around with the last code sample in chapter 4 by adding background colors to see the various bounding boxes of the elements.

However, when I ran the test app on Android I noticed that on Android there was an extra "box" added above each label of text that was added to the `textStack`.

But, a picture says more than a thousand words:

This is the output from my iOS version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpvXb.jpg

And this is the output of my Android version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cux4C.jpg

As you can see, in the Android version there is an "extra" blue box above each label of text displayed.

This is my code of `BlackCatPage` class from chapter 4, which is pretty much the same as the one in the book albeit some color changes:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BlackCat
{
    public class BlackCatPage : ContentPage
    {
        public BlackCatPage ()
        {
            StackLayout mainStack = new StackLayout ();
            StackLayout textStack = new StackLayout {
                Padding = new Thickness (5),
                Spacing = 10,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Red
            };

            Assembly assembly = GetType ().GetTypeInfo ().Assembly;
            String resource = "BlackCat.Texts.lorem.txt";

            using(Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource)) {
                using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
                    bool gotTitle = false;
                    string line;

                    while(null != (line = reader.ReadLine())) {
                        Label label = new Label {
                            Text = line,
                            TextColor = Color.White,
                            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue
                        };

                        if(!gotTitle) {
                            label.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                            label.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, label);
                            label.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
                            label.TextColor = Color.Black;
                            label.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;
                            mainStack.Children.Add(label);
                            gotTitle = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            textStack.Children.Add(label);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView {
                Content = textStack,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Padding = new Thickness(5, 0)
            };

            mainStack.Children.Add(scrollView);

            Content = mainStack;

            BackgroundColor = Color.White;

            Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to understand why on Android there is an extra blue box rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Empty lines!

My text source contains an empty line between paragraphs. It seems that there is a slight difference between iOS and Android on how these are rendered. I.e, iOS seems to skip them and Android seems to include them (not sure why yet).

Anyhow, knowing what's causing the problem, for the moment inserting a simple empty line check to avoid creating an empty `Label`'s seems to do the job:

```
while(null != (line = reader.ReadLine())) {
  if (line.Trim().Length == 0) {
    continue;
  }

  ...
}
```